# Compare two cells for whole column

Tags: excel, vba

I have to check whether two cells are equal or not, if they are equal than it should show "True" else "False".

**So condition is if cell "BP2"="BP3" than BQ2= "True" Else "False"
like this for whole column.**

This is what I tried-

```
If Sheets("A").Range("BP2") = Sheets("A").Range("BP3") Then
   
   Sheets("A").Range("BQ2") = "TRUE"

Else
    
    Sheets("A").Range("BQ2") = "FALSE"

End If

    Sheets("A").Range("BQ2").Copy Sheets("A").Range("BQ3:BQ" & LastRow)
```

I don't know how to apply for whole column. The thing that I know is that this last code line is checking BP2=BP3 for whole BQ column. and I don't know how to resolve this. help me on this

Comment: This can easily be done with a formula, it is absolutely bad idea to do that with VBA (which is much harder and very likely much slower than a formula). Just write the formula `=(BP2=BP3)` into cell `BQ2` and pull it down.

Comment: Acutally this is a huge file and i have to automate this, because data changes every time. Like this i have 750 columns in 8  sheets of a single workbook  to calculate.  and data of workbook every month changes. so i dont want to do the same thing every month for days. First i tried with functions but there are few things like "Deleting rows based on specific value" and then merging them are not possible with functions. So i am using these codes.

Comment: Then automate the formula. Still using formula would be much easier to automate, and probably faster

Comment: I think you have not understood, i know using formula is easy, but we can't do everything with functions and formulas, how can you delete the rows based on some cell value and then merge the other rows with functions in every sheet. I dont think there is any formula or anything to automate deleting and merging in every sheet

Comment: Your question is only about comparing columns (no deleting and merging in your question)! Comparing can be done by formula. Note you can write the formula with VBA too, that makes it automated but still easier and faster than comparing with VBA itself. Also you then can use filters for example to collect desired data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following R1C1 formula:

```
Sheets("A").Range("BQ2:BQ" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]=R[1]C[-1])"
```

This inserts `=(BP2=BP3)` in BQ2, `=(BP3=BP4)` in BQ3.. etc.

If you then want to remove the formula to leave the result static:

```
Sheets("A").Range("BQ2:BQ" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("A").Range("BQ2:BQ" & LastRow).Value
```

Comment: Thank You CLR for helping, I tried this and it worked-      Sheets("A").Range("BQ2").Formula = "=BP3 = BP2 "
Sheets("A").Range("BQ2").Copy Sheets("A").Range("BQ3:BQ" & LastRow)

Comment: You *can* use the copy/paste buffer if you wish, but its not recommended as other things can impact the buffer during runtime.

Comment: You have an answer to the question you've raised. Feel free to mark it as answered if it has solved the problem. If you have a further question, you need to raise that separately as a new question so that gets looked at properly.